# Is it possible to maintain server from account without admin rights?

Tags: server, security

I am wondering how should I proceed if I want to hire someone to maintain my Ubuntu server. If I give admin rights to his account he may do a lot of damage if he decides to, but if I don't give him admin rights I guess he can't do lots of maintenance.

How do you people who hire someone to maintain or do some work on your server proceed in this case?

Comment: Not an expert, but what it comes to my mind is that a partial solution would be to give his user `sudo` permissions only to run the tools needed for task he is entitled to do (via `/etc/sudoers`), however giving him permissions to, say, use `nano` as root to edit configurations files will give him the ability to edit also configuration files he shouldn't touch, so to edit configurations files, for example, it would be better to set the group of the configurations files to a custom group (say "mantainance") and add him to the group.

Comment: The general rule-of-thumb is if you don't trust someone to work on your server, find someone you do trust -- or do it yourself.